# Filter data using date range using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

What am I missing here?

Python Script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
import sys
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import datetime

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

today = datetime.date.today()
three_mon_rel = relativedelta(months=-3)
three_months_period = (today + three_mon_rel).strftime('%m/%d/%Y').lstrip('0')

data = pd.read_csv('output.csv')
rslt_df = data[data['collectedDate'] >= three_months_period]
print(rslt_df)
```

CSV file:

| ageRange | city | collectedDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 60 to 69 | A | 1/22/2021 |
| 10 to 19 | B | 10/14/2020 |
| 70 to 79 | C | 4/29/2021 |
| 80 to 89 | C | 6/23/2021 |
| 50 to 59 | A | 7/23/2020 |
| 50 to 59 | B | 7/23/2020 |
| 30 to 39 | B | 9/14/2020 |
| 50 to 59 | B | 3/13/2021 |
| 20 to 29 | A | 4/23/2020 |
| 20 to 29 | A | 7/2/2020 |
| 0 to 9 | A | 6/22/2020 |
| 60 to 69 | A | 7/7/2020 |
| 20 to 29 | B | 12/18/2020 |
| 40 to 49 | C | 10/7/2020 |
| 0 to 9 | A | 7/11/2020 |
| 10 to 19 | A | 12/18/2020 |
| 0 to 9 | C | 4/21/2021 |

I need to extract (filter) to a new table the records that meet the criteria, that is, any record that is equal or greater than three_months_period. The script executes successfully but returns all records except the first one. I am expecting the following result:

| ageRange | city | collectedDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 70 to 79 | C | 4/29/2021 |
| 80 to 89 | C | 6/23/2021 |
| 0 to 9 | C | 4/21/2021 |

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If `collectedDate` is a `datetime` filtering is a lot easier.

Via [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```
# Conver to_datetime
df['collectedDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['collectedDate'])

# Filter dates that are after now minus the relativedelta
three_mon_rel = relativedelta(months=3)
filtered_df = df[df['collectedDate'] >= pd.Timestamp.now() - three_mon_rel]
```

`filtered_df`:

```
    ageRange city collectedDate
2   70 to 79    C    2021-04-29
3   80 to 89    C    2021-06-23
16    0 to 9    C    2021-04-21
```

---

Optional convert back to string [`dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) + [`str.lstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html) ([`copy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) is used here to avoid `SettingWithCopyWarning`):

```
df['collectedDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['collectedDate'])

three_mon_rel = relativedelta(months=3)
filtered_df = df[
    df['collectedDate'] >= pd.Timestamp.now() - three_mon_rel
].copy()
filtered_df['collectedDate'] = (
    filtered_df['collectedDate'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y').str.lstrip('0')
)
```

`filtered_df`:

```
    ageRange city collectedDate
2   70 to 79    C     4/29/2021
3   80 to 89    C     6/23/2021
16    0 to 9    C     4/21/2021
```

---

DataFrame and imports:

```
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ageRange': ['60 to 69', '10 to 19', '70 to 79', '80 to 89', '50 to 59',
                 '50 to 59', '30 to 39', '50 to 59', '20 to 29', '20 to 29',
                 '0 to 9', '60 to 69', '20 to 29', '40 to 49', '0 to 9',
                 '10 to 19', '0 to 9'],
    'city': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B',
             'C', 'A', 'A', 'C'],
    'collectedDate': ['1/22/2021', '10/14/2020', '4/29/2021', '6/23/2021',
                      '7/23/2020', '7/23/2020', '9/14/2020', '3/13/2021',
                      '4/23/2020', '7/2/2020', '6/22/2020', '7/7/2020',
                      '12/18/2020', '10/7/2020', '7/11/2020', '12/18/2020',
                      '4/21/2021']
})
```